# Neo4j: how do I use an index in a relationship between two nodes?

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

I'm debugging the code of an api and I found a cypher instruction that takes 6 minutes to return the data.

I ran the neo4j code in smaller chunks and found that this snippet is causing the problem: `MATCH(copart:CopartOperadora) WHERE NOT (copart)-[:FROM_TO]->(:Coexistence)`

I'm new to neo4j so I still haven't figured out how I can optimize this instruction.

Thanks to everyone who contributed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimizations of this kind, usually depend on the schema, of your graph database, without that it's very hard to provide any insights. But you can try this:

```
MATCH (copart:CopartOperadora)-[:FROM_TO]->(:Coexistence)
WITH collect(id(copart)) AS connectedNodesIds
MATCH (copart:CopartOperadora) WHERE id(copart) NOT IN connectedNodesIds
```

We can't create any index as such, unfortunately.  But if the relationship `FROM_TO` is only present from `CopartOperadora` to `Coexistence` nodes. Then you can remove the node label for `Coexistence`, all together, which will be optimal. Something like this:

```
MATCH(copart:CopartOperadora) WHERE NOT (copart)-[:FROM_TO]->()
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your contribution :-)

Unfortunately, this query is also taking a long time to return.

The full query is too long, so I've only posted the slow part of it:
'MATCH(copart:CopartOperadora) WHERE NOT (copart)-[:FROM_TO]->(:Coexistence)'.
In this snippet I am basically looking for the 'CopartsOperador' node which has no relation to the 'Coexistence' node

I would like to create a index of contents to optimize this snippet, can you tell me if it is possible?, if so how could I create it? I didn't find anything similar in the documentation.

thanks.